# How to refer to shell script inside shared jenkins library

Tags: docker, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have a Jenkinsfile that uses the shared Jenkins lib and calls method inside the groovy file defined below.

```
shared-jenkins-lib
    |
    |-----------vars
    |            |-------pipeline_script.groovy
    |
    |-----------scripts
                 |-------test_script.groovy
```

This is the structure of the library and `pipeline_script.groovy` has a method `test` which is called from jenkinsfile.

```
def test(){
    dockerArgs = "--entrypoint /bin/bash"
    dockerCommand = "`../scripts/test_script.sh`"
    dockerOut = sh (script: "docker run ${dockerArgs} ${image} ${dockerCommand}", returnStatus: true)
}
```

I refer `test_script.sh` but doesn't seem to find the file in that location.
I am running jenkins within docker. What is the correct way to refer to the script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in the [docs](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/) of the shared libraries plugin, a library repo has a very specific structure. The root of the repo can have the following 3 folders:

```
+- src                     # Groovy source files
|   +- org
|       +- foo
|           +- Bar.groovy  # for org.foo.Bar class
+- vars
|   +- foo.groovy          # for global 'foo' variable
|   +- foo.txt             # help for 'foo' variable
+- resources               # resource files (external libraries only)
|   +- org
|       +- foo
|           +- bar.json    # static helper data for org.foo.Bar
```

If you want to refer to a helper code/data from your library method, you should put it in the `resources` directory, and then you can retrieve it with the `libraryResource` step, also described in the docs.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass in the workflowscript object into `test()`.

```
  def test(workFlowScript wfs) {
     ...
     wfs.sh ''
     wfs.echo ''
     wfs.withCredentials()
  }
```

```
// your Jenkisnfile which call test()
test(this) // this is the instance of workFlowScript
```